# Want to create react website design where image overlap on another with text side by to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, figma

I want to design a website having a design where the image is overlapping the other image and text is side by the image with different positions . I am not able to code the design using positions or grid or flexbox . Need a code to do the design
[this is the design i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPoFv.jpg)
the image is given above.

I have try to use the position absolute , flexbox , grid layout but not able to get the desired results.
If any one can help it will be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rearrange your approach as following:

- First you will place the big image with the first paragraph as you would normally do.
- Second you will place inside a **div** the small image and the second paragraph.
- Lastly you will make this div **position: absolute** and then **left: 50%** (you can adjust this based on the result you want)

Example code given:

For the HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
      <img src="" alt="this is the big image" />
      <p>This is your big paragraph</p>
      <div class="small-container">
        <img src="" alt="small image" />
        <p>Small paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

For the CSS:

```
/* This is the parent element */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.small-container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%; /*you might want to adjust this*/
}
```